# How to add elements of the same columns under such condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a column such that, C11 = A11+A21. C21 = A31+A41. But i am not sure how to do that! Unfortunately, if I write the first code as C11 = A11+A21, and try to pull it below, the excel will read the C21 as = C21 = A21 + A31...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do other cells in column C (Such as C12, C13 ) have content?

If not, please try the formula `=IF(MOD(ROW(),10)=1,INDIRECT("A"&(INT(ROW()/10)-1)*20+11)+INDIRECT("A"&(INT(ROW()/10)-1)*20+21),"")` in C11, and then drop down.

[image]